# Object required error in IE8

Tags: javascript

Actually I am working on asp web application which designed by previous employee,
I am actually handling that application after him,

So, I am facing some sort of problem when I open that application in IE8 the problem is

> Object required

```
 function getAjaxResponseListe(ther,theval)
  {
   //Specif Prix Sign IN
   pIDType=1
   //if (document.FormMTI.ON_IDType[1].checked){pIDType=2}
   if (document.getElementById('IDType_2').checked){pIDType=2}
   pIDFamille=2
   //if (document.FormMTI.ON_IDFamille[1].checked){pIDFamille=3}
   if (document.getElementById('IDFamille_2').checked){pIDFamille=3}
      pIDMode=1
   //if (document.FormMTI.ON_IDMode[1].checked){pIDMode=2}
   if (document.getElementById('IDMode_2').checked){pIDMode=2}
       switch (ther) 
        { 
        case 1: 
          pIDType=theval;
          break;
        case 2: 
          pIDFamille=theval;
          break;
        case 3: 
          pIDMode=theval;
          break;
         }
```

Please ignore the bracket open close i copy half code of javascript file, this is a javascript file when I run application I will gives error on line:6 (count from 1st line)
so how can I solve the problem...??
If you need any other file then tell me...
Actually I am new here..!!

Comment: I bet there is no 'pIDType_2' element in your HTML.

Comment: yes yes u right Actully this is only IDtype_2, IDDamille_2 & IDMode_2,

Comment: Please Help me anyone I am very upset, please solve that problem its gives error....

Comment: Please show your HTML. The part where are the elements IDType_2 and so on.

Comment: we cant help without seeing the html. show your HTML with relevant tags

Answer (score 0):

In

```
 if (document.getElementById('pIDType_2').checked==true){pIDType=2;}
```

you are accessing: document, getElementById and some element whose ID is pIDType_2. Some of them does not exist or is not accesible. Add code to test which is generating the error.

Try to include

```
if (typeof document !== 'object') {
    alert('document not found');
} else if (typeof document.getElementById !== 'function'){
    alert('getElementById not found');
} else if ( document.getElementById('pIDType_2') === null  ){
    alert('pIDType_2 not found');
} else {
    alert( typeof document.getElementById('pIDType_2').checked  );
};
```

and see what happens